# Eclipse Android not working in VirtualBox Guest OS

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am not able to start android project in Eclipse which is installed in Virtualbox Guest OS (Windows 8.1). I am getting Theme error and I googled but no result found. Similarly I get ADT Update message. My current ADT version is the latest 6.0.4

please help

Thanks

Comment: Post error / logs

Comment: Why do it in a VM?  Eclipse runs on Windows, Linux and Mac doesn't it?